# SWIFT : Incorrect argument label in call Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: swift, xcode

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class HGBackgroundMusic: SKScene {

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func getSoundReady() {
 var plop = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Plop", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: plop, error: nil)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()


}

func playSound() {
    audioPlayer.play()

}

}
```

In the 
    error:nil
line, an error is coming up stating: Incorrect argument label in call(have 'contentsOfURL:error:', expected'contentsOfURL:fileTypeHint:'). So I replace "error" with "fileTypeHint", and that brings up another error stating: Call can throw, but is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled. I cannot fix this though I have spent hours trying to find what to do to solve it.

Comment: From https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/: *"Have you read the whole question to yourself carefully, to make sure it makes sense and contains enough information for someone coming to it without any of the context that you already know?"*

Comment: Where does the `addChild` method come from?

Comment: It's difficult to understand your question if you don't provide more context. Where are you calling that function? What data type are you using? Be more specific.

Comment: @Vladimir Nul Here is the entire file:

Comment: A lot of this is coming from a iOS game tutorial. Here is the link if that helps:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mn47brqt2d8

Comment: You're still missing a lot of code here.  `addWall` is undefined, but I suspect the problem you're actually seeing is that `arc4random` takes no arguments.  You're probably looking for `arc4random_uniform`.

Comment: @DavidBerry Thanks David! I was missing the uniform part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your arc4random call with arc4random_uniform.

Comment: I see you're fairly new to SO.  Don't forget to upvote good answers (to your own questions as well as others) in addition to accepting them.